# How to create a function in haskell that takes a word and search it from a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell, search

I am working on a parts-of-speech tagger using haskell.
In order to do that I need to create a function that takes a word and search it in a library represented by a list of lists. So here is what I tried

```
pos = [["noun","kid","fox"],["adj","quick","brown"],["article","The"]]

search x [] = [(x, "unknown")]
search x (y:ys) 
    | elem x y == True = (x, head y) : search x ys
    | otherwise = search x ys
```

The "pos" represents the library.
The search function takes a word and the library and returns a list of tuples containing the word and the parts of speech tag.
My problem is that when I call the function like this:

search "kid" pos

it returns:

[("kid", "noun"),("kid", "unknown")]

I got it that it's because of the first line in the function search that when the input is an empty list it returns the word and unknown

```
search x [] = [(x,"unknown")]
```

showing that the word was not found. However, if I change that part into:

```
search x [] = []
```

there would be no output when the word is not found.
Can anyone suggest me methods to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution to this is to use the version of the function that returns an empty list if the output isn't found, but then "replace" an empty output with the desired `[(x, "unknown")]` value. You can even have the main lookup function as a purely local function, if you don't need it elsewhere:

```
pos = [["noun","kid","fox"],["adj","quick","brown"],["article","The"]]

search x l = case lookup x l of
    [] -> [(x, "unknown")]
    o  -> o

    where
        lookup x [] = []
        lookup x (y:ys) 
            | elem x y = (x, head y) : lookup x ys
            | otherwise = lookup x ys
```

(Note that I've eliminated the `== True` from the `elem x y` guard, this isn't necessary, a guard needs its condition to be a Boolean expression and checks if it's `True` anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

You could add an extra parameter what to return as "tail" in case it is not found, like:

```
search :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [(a, a)]
search x = go [(x, "Unknown")]
    where go t [] = t
          go t (y:ys) | elem x ys = (x, head y) : go [] ys
                      | otherwise = go t ys
```

That being said, I'm not convinced that your `search` function is designed in the correct way.

It might be better to:

1. use `[(a, [b])]` as "database", so a list of 2-tuples with `a` the "tag", and `b` the "values" for which the tag applies, and
2. you might want to return just the empty list `[]` in case it can not find the element, since it might be possible that the tag "Unknown" is also part of the database.

We can then implement this with:

```
search :: Eq a => a -> [(b, [a])] -> [(a, b)]
search x = go
    where go [] = []
          go ([]:ys) = go ys
          go ((t:vs):ys) | elem x vs = (x, t) : go ys
                         | otherwise = go ys
```